# Can a hadoop slave node be made hadoop master node without incurring data loss

Tags: hadoop

I have three node hadoop cluster. `A` `B` `C`

`A` Master

`B` slave

`C` slave

If i want to make `C` as master and the remaining as slaves will i face data loss or data corruption ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to format the NameNode when initializing new cluster configuration. so yes you might lost files that are already in the HDFS.